# android GPS still getting postion when i'm not moving

Tags: android, gps

I'm developing a tracking app. and i have problem with GPS module. The app must record a route. App work fine, but sometimes when the device is not moving, GPS still receive 
continuous coordinate that don't indicate my position, error is within a radius of 20 meter, and when I'm moving again work fine. 
Please give me some tips that can help me to fix this problem. Thanks a lot.

I have 3 calsses

1 - GPSReceiver here is method for get location

```
public void getMyLoction(){ 
    _locationManager = (LocationManager) _context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    _isGPSEnabled    =_locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);     
    if (_isGPSEnabled) {
        if (_location == null) {
            _locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, this);
            if (_locationManager != null) {                 
                _location = _locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                setLocation(_location);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

2 RecordingActivity (take coordonates form services and processes then) work fine, a comment in method what they do.

```
public class RecordingActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public final static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "map.trackv";
public BroadcastReceiver receiver;

private GoogleMap map;
private TextView _messageToUser;
private Coordinate _pointFromService;
private long _timeWhenStartButtonWasPressed;

private List<Coordinate> _unprocessedCoords;
private List<Coordinate> _processedCoords;

private Button _stopButton;
private Button _startButton;

private String _startRecordingDate;
private String _stopRecordingDate;
private GPSReceiver _gps;

private DataBaseOperations _dataSource;

private boolean _recording;
private boolean _gpsStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recording_route);
    initActvity();

    checkIfGPSisOn();
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f" + " /sdcard/Logcat.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("nu pot", "DDDDD");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    receveirWork();
    IntentFilter intentFilt = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilt);

}

public void checkIfGPSisOn() {
    //check on start
}

public void receveirWork() {

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // request points and process then, 
        }

    };
}



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();  

    if (_stopButton.isEnabled())
    {
        stopService(new Intent(this, RecordingService.class));
        _unprocessedCoords = null;
        _processedCoords   = null;
    }
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    if (!_stopButton.isEnabled()) {
        _startButton.setEnabled(true);
        _messageToUser.setText(Constants.PRESS_START_BUTTON);
        map.clear();
    }
    super.onResume();
}

// actiune buton start;
public void startButtonEvent(View V) {
    buttonsStateAndMessageToShow(false, true, Constants.MESSAGE_TO_WAIT);
    _timeWhenStartButtonWasPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();        
    startService(new Intent(this, RecordingService.class));

// start service to get position
}



public void stopButtonEvent(View V) {
    stopService(new Intent(this, RecordingService.class));
    // stop service         
    // save route in BD     
    // resetData;
}   
public void initActvity() {
    // init date    

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // save state       

}
```

}

3 RecordingServices class, ii think here is the problem.

```
public class RecordingService extends Service {

private Thread _backgroundWork;
private boolean _threadCanRun;
private GPSReceiver _gps;
private Coordinate _pointToSent;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    _threadCanRun = true;
    _backgroundWork = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            getLocationFromGPS();
            Looper.loop();

        }
    });

}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {//    
    _backgroundWork.start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    _threadCanRun = false;
    super.onDestroy();
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void getLocationFromGPS() {

    while (_threadCanRun) {
        Intent _intent = new Intent(RecordingActivity.BROADCAST_ACTION);
        _gps = new GPSReceiver(this);       

        _gps.getMyLoction();
        if (_gps.getIsGPSEnabled()) {

        try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}             
            sentPoint(_intent);

        } else {

            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

            _intent.putExtra("latitude", 0);
            _intent.putExtra("longitude", 0);
            _intent.putExtra("time", 0);
            _intent.putExtra("GPSstatus", false);
            sendBroadcast(_intent);
        }
    }
}


private void sentPoint(Intent _intent) {
    _pointToSent = new Coordinate(_gps.getLatitude(), _gps.getLongitude(),  _gps.getTime());
    _intent.putExtra("latitude", _pointToSent.getLatitude());
    _intent.putExtra("longitude", _pointToSent.getlongitude());
    _intent.putExtra("time", _pointToSent.getTime());
    _intent.putExtra("GPSstatus", _gps.getIsGPSEnabled());

    sendBroadcast(_intent);
    _pointToSent = null;

}
```

}

Comment: Please add your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

repeating the Location update request depends on how u implemented your tracking system 
but in general(which is not recommended , just change your request update rate to save client Battery usage) you can find the distance between your locations by `location1.distanceTo(location2)` so if the distance is smaller than 30m then put the new location away

Comment: it may be a solution, but in my case, 20m is a big distance, and when device is moving i need to record even small distance @Arash